# Is it appropriate to use Django's abstract classes for simple code reuse?

Tags: python, django, oop, model

I am learning Django and writing my first semi-complex model. Many of my tables are made with a similar view style in mind, so many objects have a name, a description and an image. Ex:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    # Standard to many classes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)

    # Unique to this class
    foodgroup = ..... etc.
```

Since name, description and url will be common to many objects (that are otherwise totally different), I was considering defining a base class that each can inherit from:

```
class BaseObjectWithImage(models.Model):
    # Standard to many classes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Ingredient(BaseObjectWithImage):        
    # Unique to this class
    foodgroup = ..... etc.
```

My question - which may be closer to a simple OOP Best Practices question - is whether this is a silly use of Django's abstract class, or if is worthwhile for stripping out 3xN lines of code and allowing me to treat most model classes as a generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a silly use of abstact classes.  Both Django and python are relatively polygamous in that they allow you to use many different programming styles (whichever one suits you best).  Just make sure that you are making a consistent and conscious decision as to whether the models create individual tables each with its own copy of the repeated columns or whether they each contain a ForeignKey to a common base table.